# SSRS header to be frozen while scrolling down the report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

[image]I am trying to keep header rows static while scrolling through the report in SSRS, Visual Studio 2012.

I have tried the following and it has not worked : 
Under Design Pane - > Row Groups - > click on (static) - > Press F4  - > Properties window will pop up.

In the Properties window - >Set KeepWithGroup =  After and RepeatOnNewPage = True.

If you want the header to be frozen while scrolling down the report, set FixedData = True.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the header visible while scrolling, you need to go to (right click on tablix) **Tablix Properties > General** and check the option **Keep header visible while scrolling**. Then go to column/row groups in the advanced mode, chose your static row and set the **Fixed Data** mode to `True`, **Repeat on new page** to `True` and **Keep with group** to `After`.

Here is prbably the best reference: [KeepHeaderVisible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2008/10/13/repeat-header-keep-header-visible-in-tables-in-rs-2008/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added another screenshot - is this where i need to go for the 'tablix properties' in order to check option 'keep header visible while scrolling?'

Comment: Yes this is the right one. In the link you will also find a screenshot, where to find the advanced mode

Comment: ok, cheers. I do not see the option you mentioned in the properites of the tablix though. 'Keep header visible while scrolling'

Comment: Ah my bad, the image shows the wrong properties. Right click on the tablix (left top corner) then to the tab `General`. There you will find the `Keep header visible while scrolling`