# SSRS Repeat Group Header on NEXT page

Tags: reporting-services

The current state (some text removed for the sake of company policy):

[image: Tablix Structure]
[image: Group Structure]

Now the problem, I have set the very top (Static) row which is the header with the word "Images" at the end of the tablix, but I can't set the Row Group (Customer) to repeat on the next page if all the elements does not fit on the current page. The solution should be one of two, either the whole group to go on the next page (but not every group on separate page, just the one that does not fit on the page) OR the group header to be repeated on the next page with the rest of the elements. Is this possible?

Comment: This will repeat the header on each page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590845/ssrs-header-to-be-frozen-while-scrolling-down-the-report/53591565#53591565 You can turn of the keep visible while scrolling thou

Comment: Im not sure if this is the case I need but this also uses table layout although I am using tablix

Answer (score 0):

let me know if this worked for you.
[image]

Comment: this is at you will right-click your main tabix -> properties.

Comment: Hi junketsu, I have the 'header' repeating already on each page. The problem is to make the 'group header' to repeat on the next page IF all the items from the group does not fit on the same page.